# Why I obtain this 403 Forbidden error when I try to access to this WordPress website? Why it can't read the .htaccess file?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

I have some problem trying to open this **WordPress** website: http://www.angeliniappalti.it/

As you can see trying to open it I obtain this **403 error** message, this one:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /wp-admin on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
Apache/2 Server at www.angeliniappalti.it Port 80
```

Reading online I see that it is a well know issue but I can't find a solution for my problem.

So looking into the Apache Errors Log I can see the following error message:

```
[Mon Feb 09 01:27:18 2015] [crit] [client 157.55.39.155] (13)Permission denied: /home/ang12457/domains/angeliniappalti.it/public_html/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Mon Feb 09 01:27:18 2015] [crit] [client 157.55.39.155] (13)Permission denied: /home/ang12457/domains/angeliniappalti.it/public_html/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

So it seems that it can't read the **.htaccess** file but it's permission is setted to **777** so in theory this file should be readable.

This is the content of my **.htacess** file:

```
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthUserFile /home/ang12457/domains/angeliniappalti.it/.htpasswd/public_html/.htpasswd
AuthName "area riservata"
```

The **.htaccess** file is contained into the **public_html** directory (that contains also the WordPress directory) and it have **700** as permission.

What could be the problem? What I am missing? How can I try to solve this issue?

Tnx

Comment: A lot of hosts have the requirement that you CHMOD maximum to 755. Any higher (or lower) can throw an error. Have you tried that? You should apply it to your files, see the list of required CHMOD levels here http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Comment: @NielsvanRenselaar I try to set the permssion of .htaccess file to 755 but still have the same problem

Comment: Looks like something is wrong in your apache configuration, doesn't look like a permissions issue.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by myself, I simply have changed the permission of the **public_html** directory from **700** to **750** and it works :-)